# path of visual studio c compiler

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2012, command-line, path

i use to compile c/c++ code with gcc and now i want to pass on vsc. So i read for configure the path i should go in my visual studio file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC` and use `vcvarsall.bat`. When i do that with the `powershell`, it just doesn't work. If i do it with the `cmd.exe`, i will be able the use cl but if i open a new `cmd.exe` it won't work again. I try to put manually `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin` in the path but it doesn't work either.
Thank you for all the future help.

Comment: Open a cmd window, run vcvarsall.bat, then start PowerShell from that same cmd window - the PowerShell session will then inherit the necessary environment variables.

Comment: It work, but if i reopen a windows it won't work again. If i have to do that everytime it's not very interesting,

Comment: Just make a .bat file that does this for you and put it on the desktop.

Comment: It's a normal if it does that ? Anyway, what i did it's just change the target of a powershell shortcut to `%comspec% /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"`

Comment: Yep - that works too. The holistic solution though is to ditch Windows and use a proper OS. ;-)

Comment: Actually i though vcvarsall create the path "Globally" but i read a little bit more and i understand why what i wanna do didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Finally what i did it's create a shortcut and change the target to `%comspec% /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"`.

Answer (score 0):

### Newer versions of Visual Studio/Build Tools create shortcuts for you

Lately, if you install Visual Studio or VS Build Tools - with Develop C++ Desktop applications package, you should get a bunch of shortcuts automatically in the Windows Start menu that will launch a command prompt for 64 or 32 bit compiler.

Just open start menu search bar (shortcut - Windows key) and type command:
[image]

You can do the following to find out how to run these files:

1. Right-click on the item in Windows Start and choose `Open File Location`, which will open the shortcut link in File Explorer
2. Right-click the shortcut link and choose `Properties`
3. In the Properties windows, copy the "Target:" field (click in it and ctrl-a to select all, then ctrl-c to copy).
4. The first item is the exe called (Should be `%comspec%`, and anything after the first space will be arguments.

For example, my `x64 Native Tools Commmand Prompt for VS 2019` shortcut has a target of:

```
%comspec% /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"
```

Armed with this info, you can build a profile (see below) to launch terminals from other apps, or just take the last argument - the path and name of the batch file - and run it in a command terminal to set it up correctly to find all the VC tools.

### Setting up a profile with a terminal in another tool/app

To setup a profile for apps like Microsoft's "Windows Terminal" app (multiple, tabbed terminals of different types - see Windows Store to download), or for Visual Studio Code:

Use the info from the shortcuts that link to the `vcvars.bat` batch files, as explained above to create a profile. For example, here is the JSON to add to Visual Studio Code to add an x86 (32-bit) and 64 bit command window to the dropdown list:

In `.vscode/settings.json`:

```json
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
  "Visual C Dev Prompt (x64)": {
    "path": "cmd.exe",
    "args": [
      "/k",
      "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Auxiliary\\Build\\vcvars64.bat",
    ],
  },
  "Visual C Dev Prompt (x86)": {
    "path": "cmd.exe",
    "args": [
      "/k",
      "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\Common7\\Tools\\VsDevCmd.bat",
    ],
  },
},
```

Note that I changed the calling command from `%comspec%` to just `cmd.exe`, which should be in `WINDOWS/system32` folder, which should already be on the path. I couldn't get it working with `%comspec%`. You can expand that in a command window to see the path on your PC as follows:

```
echo %comspec%
```

On my PC it was `C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

for visual studio 2022 version i found C/C++ compiler in this path `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\bin\Hostx64\x64`

- the compiler name is ```cl.exe``
- if you want 32 bit version just go to :  `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\bin\Hostx64\x86`

add it to environment paths :)